# The Contextmenu does not show up

Tags: android, contextmenu

I am trying to create a `ContextMenu` with a button. For some reason, it is not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

This is the picture_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/take_from_gallery"
    android:title="@string/str_take_from_gallery"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/take_picture"
    android:title="@string/str_take_picture"/>
  <item
    android:id="@+id/delete_picture"
    android:title="@string/str_delete_picture"/>    
</menu>
```

and this is the java code:

```
camera_button= new Button(this);
camera_button.setLongClickable(true);
registerForContextMenu(camera_button);

public void onCreateContextmenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    MenuInflater inflater= getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.picture_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info= (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.take_from_gallery:
        return true;
    case R.id.take_picture:
        return true;
    case R.id.delete_picture:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

All I need right now is to make this work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was really silly. A was mispelling the "onCreateContextMenu" function. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this can help, but maybe this is what your looking for:
[Context menu for long clicks](http://www.mikeplate.com/2010/01/21/show-a-context-menu-for-long-clicks-in-an-android-listview/)

Hope it helps :)

//Gerner

Comment: i do not work with ListView, just want to pop up a ContextMenu when i click a button. Thanks!